# Cannot select multi-valued objects in a result clause of a query

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to the following query in  jdo for optimization purposes

```
Query myQuery = pm.newQuery(MyInstance.class);
myQuery.setResult("this.id,this.myField");
myQuery.setResultClass(MyResultInstance.class);
myQuery.execute();
```

Calling execute will throw the following exception due to myField being a byte array (`byte[] myField;`)

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Cannot select multi-valued objects in a result clause of a query
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Cannot select multi-valued objects in a result clause of a query
    net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.logThrowable(Filter.java:143)
    net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:91)
```

Is there any way of getting around this limitation? I can change it to whatever type as long as I can serialize it in any way to a hash map in the end. It's possible for datanucleus to serialize clobs into strings, so why not support this for blobs?

Is there a byte array type that does not implement `AbstractContainerMapping`?

Using datanucleus version 4.0.2

Comment: well JPQL doesn't define support for selecting multi-valued fields in a select clause so hardly surprising. Post the MyInstance class so we can see what fields are there, and the real stack trace of where the exception is thrown from

Comment: @NeilStockton I'm not using JPA, also I understand that multi-valued fields are not supported in resultClasses. However serialized object could be seen as a single valued item in the same way as a string is (a character array). I'm wondering if there is a work around to retrieve a blob object in a result class

Comment: I mean if I would encode this in base64 for instance it would work, however this would be a very inefficient work around =)

Comment: Whether it is JDOQL or JPQL, the same comment applies. That said, I see no reason why it shouldn't be allowed when the array (or collection, or map) is serialized into a single column of the table of the owning object. Perhaps raise it on their forum?

Comment: Thanks, reposted on their forum